# TypeError: String.fromCodePoint is not a function, an error in the node modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am doing a react project and is using basic libraries, I get these weird errors in the console saying there are errors in the module files

```
"dependencies": {
"concurrently": "^7.3.0",
"cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
"express": "^4.18.1",
"mongodb": "^4.9.1",
"mongoose": "^6.5.4",
"nodemon": "^2.0.19",
"passport": "^0.5.3",
"passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0"
```

}

the error I get:

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\webidl-conversions\lib\index.js:272
> [0]       U.push(String.fromCodePoint(c));
> [0]                     ^
> [0]
> [0] TypeError: String.fromCodePoint is not a function
> [0]     at Object.exports.USVString
> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\webidl-conversions\lib\index.js:272:21)
> [0]     at new URL (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\whatwg-
> url\lib\URL.js:99:42)
> [0]     at new URLWithoutHost (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongodb-
> connection-string-url\lib\index.js:74:1)
> [0]     at new ConnectionString (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongodb-
> connection-string-url\lib\index.js:126:13)
> [0]     at parseOptions
> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:209:17)
> [0]     at new MongoClient  (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_clien
> t.js:64:63)
> [0]     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:801:16
> [0]     at new Promise ()
> [0]     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri
> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:798:19)
> [0]     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\mylibrary\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10

my frontend is react with typescript template
backend I used node js and express
and I am using mongoos/mongodb as my db
and google auth for signing in and out

Comment: Please have a look at the code of conduct, for asking questions. Your question needs more information to be able to solve the problem or error you are facing.

Comment: I am new here so I do not know what more info I should add, would really appeciate help

Answer (score -1):

I changed the mongoose version to 5.13.13 and it kind of solved the issue, I now have a different issue but not sure if related